# Good practices for services on Android

Tags: android, service, geolocation, xmpp

I am currently using 2 services in my app:

**1: LocationService**, basically trying to localize the user, and aims to stay alive only when the app is on foreground.

**2: XmppService**, which init the connection with the xmpp server, receive messages, send it, logout ... and aims to stay alive until the user logout.

I've been reading quite a lot of documentation, but I just can't make it clear.

I'm having ***Leaks*** when I try to store reference of LocationServiceBinder, which is used to call my service functions (*using AIDL interfaces*). Same for Xmpp. When I unbind, I get sometimes ANR (*which look like to be linked with the fact that my bind/unbind are weirdly done, onResume, onRestart ...*).

All **the system is working**, but I'm sure it is not the right way to do it, and please I would love to follow experienced people to come back in the right side of the force ! :)

Cheers

**UPDATE**

My Location Service is bind at the app launch to get as fast as possible the user's position :

```
if(callConnectService == null) {
            callConnectService = new ServiceConnection() {
                public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder binder) {
                    locationServiceBinder = LocationServiceBinder.Stub.asInterface(binder);
                    try {
                        global.setLocationBinder(locationServiceBinder); 
                        global.getLocationBinder().startLocationListener();
                    } catch (Exception e){
                        Log.e(TAG, "Service binder ERROR");
                    }
                }

                public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
                    locationServiceBinder = null;
                }
            };
        }

        /* Launch Service */
        aimConServ =  new Intent(this, LocationService.class);
        boolean bound = bindService(aimConServ,callConnectService,BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

My Xmpp Service is launched when the user log in :

callConnectService = new ServiceConnection() {

```
            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder binder) {
                try {
                    Log.d(TAG, "[XMPP_INIT] Complete.");
                    global.setServiceBinder(ConnectionServiceBinder.Stub.asInterface(binder)); 
                    //Connect to XMPP chat
                    global.getServiceBinder().connect();
                } catch (Exception e){
                    Log.e(TAG, "Service binder ERROR ");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Service binder disconnection ");
            }
        };

        /* Launch Service */
        Intent aimConServ =  new Intent(MMWelcomeProfile.this, XmppService.class);
        bound = bindService(aimConServ,callConnectService,Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

and unbind on each Activity :

```
if (callConnectService != null){
        unbindService(callConnectService);
        callConnectService = null;
    }
```

Comment: Post some code snippet where your bind/unbind service in your problematic activity may help others find your problem.

Comment: Updated, just added some code

Answer (score 1):

It hasn't been well-documented in Google's official dev guide, Context.bindService() is actually an asynchronous call. This is the reason why ServiceConnection.onServiceConnected() is used as a callback method, means not happened immediately.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
  private MyServiceBinder myServiceBinder;

  protected ServiceConnection myServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
      myServiceBinder = (MyServiceBinderImpl) service;
    }

    ... ...
  }

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // bindService() is an asynchronous call. myServiceBinder is resoloved in onServiceConnected()
    bindService(new Intent(this, MyService.class),myServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    // You will get a null point reference here, if you try to use MyServiceBinder immediately.
    MyServiceBinder.doSomething(); // <-- not yet resolved so Null point reference here
  }
}
```

A workaround is call MyServiceBinder.doSomething() in myServiceConnection.onServiceConnected(), or perform MyServiceBinder.doSomething() by some user interaction (e.g. button click), as the lag after you call bindService() and before system get a reference of myServiceBinder is quite soon. as long as you are not using it immediately, you should be just fine.

Check out this SO question [CommonsWare's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3358230/how-to-bind-to-running-android-service) for more details.

Comment: Yep, I'm totally aware it's an asynchronous call, and I get into the onServiceConnected I keep the reference of the binder in my custom Application, but giving me leaks if I don't unbind, but If I do, service dies

Comment: Where do you call unbindService()? Does your service create/manage thread itself?

Comment: For the location service, it manages itself and is not supposed to do anything while it has no signal from the application. But I would like to be able to unbind it when my application goes in background, and re-bind when relaunched. For the xmpp service I bind/ unbind on each Activity. But I have so weird behaviour sometimes , including leaks

Comment: The real thing I don't know how to do, Is launching (bind) a service from an activity, and re-use the SAME service later ?

Answer (score 0):

this thread is quite old, but I just discovered it.

Actually there is only one way for your service to go on living if it is bound : it has to be also started. The documentation is not quite clear about that but a service can be both started and bound.

In that case, the service will not get destroyed when you unbind from it, it will get destroyed when  :

- you stop it and there is no one bound to it
- you unbind from it and it has been stopped before.

I made a small Service Lifecycle demo app [on GitHub](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/MixedServiceLifeCycle-sample) and it's also available on [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.snicolas.mixedservicelifecycle&hl=fr).

Hope that helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

if you bind to a service in an Activity, you need to unbind it too:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {

    Log.d("activity", "onResume");
    if (locationServiceBinder == null) {
        doBindLocationService();
    }
            super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {

    Log.d("activity", "onPause");
    if (locationServiceBinder  != null) {
        unbindService(callConnectService);
        locationServiceBinder = null;
    }
    super.onPause();
}
```

where *doBindLocationService()*:

```
public void doBindLocationService() {
    Log.d("doBindService","called");

    aimConServ =  new Intent(this, LocationService.class);
    // Create a new Messenger for the communication back
    // From the Service to the Activity
    bindService(aimConServ, callConnectService, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}
```

You need to do this practise for your *XmppService* as well