# Android : Can bind to a service but cannot receive instance variables

Tags: android, android-service, smack, asmack

How do I receive instance variables declared in the service , I am able to bind to a service ,  but while accessing function to get XMPPConnection to get instance variable , I get Null Pointer exception:

Here is my code:

```
public class hotListener extends Activity {

    private MyService service;
    private XMPPConnection connection;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listener);
        if(!isMyServiceRunning()){
            startService(new Intent(this,MyService.class));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        bindService(new Intent(this, MyService.class), mConnection,Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        System.out.println("bind done");

        connection = service.getConnection();
        System.out.println("connection received");
        receivespots();
    }

    private void receivespots() {
            //ChatManager chatmanager = connection.getChatManager();
            connection.getChatManager().addChatListener(new ChatManagerListener() {

                @Override
                public void chatCreated(Chat arg0, boolean arg1) {
                    arg0.addMessageListener(new MessageListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void processMessage(Chat arg0, Message arg1) {
                            System.out.print(arg0);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
    }

    private boolean isMyServiceRunning() {
        System.out.println("get called");
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for(RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)){
            if(MyService.class.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())){
                System.out.print("true");
                return true;
            }
        }
        System.out.print("false");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
      protected void onResume() {
        bindService(new Intent(this, MyService.class), mConnection,
            Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        super.onResume();
      }
     @Override
      protected void onPause() {
        unbindService(mConnection);
        super.onPause();
      }

     private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

            @Override
            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
                connection = null;
                service = null;

            }

            @Override
            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder binder) {
                service = ((MyService.MyBinder)binder).getService();
                Log.d("Service","connected");
                Toast.makeText(hotListener.this,"connected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };
}
```

Is there anything wrong in my approach , I am using asmack .

Code for service:

```
public class MainService extends Service{
private XMPPConnection connection;
private final IBinder mBinder = new MyBinder();

    @Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mBinder;
}

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
Log.d("service","started");
new Connect().execute("");
return START_STICKY;
    }

    private class Connect extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    ConnectionConfiguration connConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration(SERVICE,PORT);
    XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(connConfig);
    try {
        connection.connect();
        Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity",
                "Connected to " + connection.getHost());
    } catch (XMPPException ex) {
        Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Failed to connect to "
                + connection.getHost());
        Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", ex.toString());
        setConnection(null);
    }
    try {
        // SASLAuthentication.supportSASLMechanism("PLAIN", 0);
        connection.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
        Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity",
                "Logged in as " + connection.getUser());

        // Set the status to available
        Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);
        connection.sendPacket(presence);
        setConnection(connection);
        Roster roster = connection.getRoster();
        Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();
        for (RosterEntry entry : entries) {
            Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity",
                    "--------------------------------------");
            Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "RosterEntry " + entry);
            Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity",
                    "User: " + entry.getUser());
            Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity",




        "Name: " + entry.getName());
            Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity",
                    "Status: " + entry.getStatus());
            Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity",
                    "Type: " + entry.getType());
            Presence entryPresence = roster.getPresence(entry
                    .getUser());

            Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Presence Status: "
                    + entryPresence.getStatus());
            Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Presence Type: "
                    + entryPresence.getType());
            Presence.Type type = entryPresence.getType();
            if (type == Presence.Type.available)
                Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Presence AVIALABLE");
            Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Presence : "
                    + entryPresence);

        }
    } catch (XMPPException ex) {
        Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Failed to log in as "
                + USERNAME);
        Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", ex.toString());
        setConnection(null);
    }
    return null;       
}}

    public void setConnection(XMPPConnection connection) {
this.connection = connection;
if (connection != null) {
    // Add a packet listener to get messages sent to us
    PacketFilter filter = new MessageTypeFilter(Message.Type.chat);
    connection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener() {
        public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
            Message message = (Message) packet;
            if (message.getBody() != null) {
                String fromName = StringUtils.parseBareAddress(message
                        .getFrom());
                Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Text Recieved " + message.getBody()
                        + " from " + fromName );
            }
        }
    }, filter);
}
    }

   public class MyBinder extends Binder 
    {
        MainService getService() {
        return MainService.this;
      }
      }

    public XMPPConnection getconnection()
    {
if (connection != null) {
    Log.d("MainService","connection send");
    return connection;  
}
else
{
    Log.d("MainService","connection null");
return null;    
}
```

}}

EDIT: added code to service

I can successfully bind from other activity but here I need to use connection variable to set message listener in separate activity

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8341782/good-practices-for-services-on-android yorkw answer somewhat address this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem are these lines

```
    connection = service.getConnection();
    System.out.println("connection received");
    receivespots();
```

At this point your `service` variable has not been set, you are setting it for the first time on `onServiceConnected`. So I would suggest moving those three lines after this line

```
service = ((MyService.MyBinder)binder).getService();
```

EDIT:
Now you're talking about a different error. I can't know because you didn't post the code of your service class. You need to read the documentation carefully, because binding to a service can be very tricky. You need to have something like this:

```
private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    Log("onBind");
    return mBinder;
}

public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    MyService getService() {
        return MyService.this;
    }
}
```

Comment: but service variable should have been set after this call         bindService(new Intent(this, HotspotService.class), mConnection,Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
, may be I should instantiate it to null first

Comment: No, `service` variable should NOT have been set after bindService, because that method is asynchronous, meaning the method returns but there's no guarantee it has finished it's job. That's why you have the `onServiceConnected` callback

Comment: Still getting Nullpointer exception at this line : service = ((MyService.MyBinder)binder).getService(); Declared binder as  private IBinder binder;

Comment: Hey added code for service, I am using binder as specified

Comment: @user595169 Hmmm, your code seems right to me! Can you check if the `binder` variable is not null?