# update Textview of a layout from a service

Tags: android, service, textview, inflate

I want to update a Textview in a layout, when a Service detects that a call is missed,
i'm using this code in onCreat method in my service:

```
    public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    final LayoutInflater mcInflator = (LayoutInflater) ctext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );

    bla bla bla bla bla
    ...

if (call.toString().contains("Missed")){

                    View mcLayout= mcInflator.inflate(R.layout.m_call, null );
                    TextView mc = (TextView) mcLayout.findViewById(R.id.mcText);
                    mc.setText("Missed Call");
                }

                if (call.toString().contains("Outgoing")){

  bla bla bla bla bla ....
```

but when i check my lay out, Textview is not changed? any suggestion please?

Comment: **"any suggestion please?"** - Yes...don't try to do this. Firstly you can't guarantee an `Activity` will actually exist. Secondly, you can't inflate or gain access to a view that's in an `Activity` from a `Service`. Thirdly, why would you want to do this? If I miss a call I get a notification telling me that I missed the call - it's the correct way of notifying somebody there has been a missed call - not in a `TextView` of an `Activity` which may or may not be running.

Answer (score 0):

Oh my... OK, here we go:

- You do not want to do any UI stuff in the service. That is pretty bad practice.
- You are creating and modifying a new instance of your view, not the one that is displayed on the screen.
- What you probably want to do is binding the running service in your activity. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3358230/how-to-bind-to-running-android-service) for an example.